# color formatting one cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make column A change to yellow if column B is 42. I have column B set up as =unichar(42) which makes it show * and I have * set up to be yellow.

Comment: Start here: https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html

Comment: Add a rule to column A with the formula `=$B1="*"`

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I needed.